# TypeError: Cannot read property 'vaseID' of undefined at eval (Vase.js:22)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django-rest-framework, axios, use-state

I am new to react and API's (student). I am trying to retrieve and populate my component with a Vase record from the database. Im receiving a TypeError of undefined for vaseID.There is a record there so its not an empty JSON. What am i doing wrong?

```
import React,{useEffect,useState} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';


const Vase=()=>{
    const [Data,setData]=useState({
        VaseID:'',
        Subject:'',
    })
    useEffect(()=>{
        axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/viewvaseapi/')
            .then(res=>{
                console.log('Response from main API: ',res)
                console.log('Home Data: ',res.data.ad)
                let vaseData=res.data.ad;
                setData({VaseID:vaseData.VaseID,Subject:vaseData.subject})
            })
            .catch(err=>{
                console.log(err);
            })
    },[])
    return(
        <>
            <h1>{Data.VaseID}</h1>
            <p>{Data.Subject}</p>
        </>
    )
}
export default Vase;
```

Comment: What do you get when you `console.log(vaseData)` before calling `setData`

Comment: i got 'undefined'

Comment: Well, that is the issue. Can't read `VaseID` of undefined. The problem is you can't get any data.

Comment: i can see the data on the console from console.log('Home Data: ',res.data.ad). What do i need to change?

Comment: What is the `res.data.ad` there?

Comment: {data: Array(1), status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}
config: {url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/viewvaseapi/", method: "get", headers: {…}, transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), …}
data: Array(1)
0: {id: 5, vaseID: "44", inscription: "", fabric: "Paestan", subject: "[a) Three maenads and a bearded silen, [b) two draped youths.", …}
length: 1

Comment: my apologies, Just realised console.log('Home Data:', res.data.ad) is undefined. 
The response above is the res from console.log('Response from main API: ',res)

Comment: Since `res.data` is an array, you probably want something like `res.data[0].ad`